# Getting SIGPIPE with non-blocking sockets -- is this normal?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, signals, epoll

I'm writing an epoll-based network server in C.  When I create my socket to listen for incoming connections, I make it non-blocking using `fcntl`.  Similarly when incoming connections arrive from clients, I make their sockets non-blocking before doing anything with them, and likewise for outgoing connections' sockets.

Sometimes my server gets a SIGPIPE -- I *think* this is when I try to write to a client connection that has been closed by the client.  This seems strange to me; I thought that with non-blocking sockets instead of a SIGPIPE I should get an `-1` back from the call to `write` and `ECONNRESET` in `errno`.

Is there something I'm missing?  Or is it just normal to get both a SIGPIPE and an error code even with non-blocking sockets (meaning that I should explicitly ignore the signal with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` in my setup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. If you write to a socket (non-blocking or not) where the other end has closed the connection, you will get a `SIGPIPE` or (if you are blocking the `SIGPIPE` signal) an error return (`-1`) with `errno` set to `EPIPE`.

From the man page for `write`:

> `EPIPE`:  `fd` is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this happens the writing process will also receive
>   a `SIGPIPE` signal.  (Thus, the write return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)

The POSIX standard is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html and says:

> `[EPIPE]` An attempt is made to write to a pipe or FIFO that is not open for reading by any process, or that only has one end open. A `SIGPIPE` signal shall also be sent to the thread.

Comment: Thanks!  Don't know how I managed to miss that.  I'll add the SIG_IGN handler.  Will I ever get ECONNRESET?  Or is that for something else, and I just need to look for EPIPE?

Comment: The POSIX standard (but not the linux manpage) says you will get `ECONNRESET` if the socket was never connected in the first place. Assuming you treat `EINTR`, `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` specially, then in general I treat any other error condition as fatal and assume the connection is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The SIGPIPE is normal. Another option beside setting signal handler solely for this purpose is to use flag MSG_NOSIGNAL whenever you send.